# install msal-angular not working peer rxjs@"^6.0.0" from @azure/msal-angular@2.1.1

Tags: angular, azure, npm, npm-scripts

i want to install @azure/msal-angular to work with azure B2C authentication using angular as a front end but when i try to install the package it gives me an error

```
    npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: ng-x-rocket@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: rxjs@7.5.4
npm ERR! node_modules/rxjs
npm ERR!   rxjs@"^7.4.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer rxjs@"^6.0.0" from @azure/msal-angular@2.1.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@azure/msal-angular
npm ERR!   @azure/msal-angular@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /home/kareem/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/kareem/.npm/_logs/2022-02-20T10_30_25_156Z-debug-0.log
```

could you help me i tried different ways to fix this issue but unfortunately nothing happens

what i have tried is:

```
npm install -g npm-install-peers
```

remove node_modules directory and reinstall packages by npm install or npm cache clean and npm install.

Answer (score 3):

Angular 13 has RxJS v7 dependency, while MSAL library  currently *(2022-02-20)* only supports RxJS up to 6.5.5.

see: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/4154

There are some workarounds involving downgrading your RxJS to v6 (since Angular 13 also supports RxJS v6). You can find them in this github thread I linked.